# How to acces data from variable in begin function

Tags: javascript

Could someone help me out on this function structure what I try to do is seperate the functions like this:

```
function getNewResources (currentUrl, nextUrl)
    {
        let resourcesCurrentUrl = getResourceByUrl(currentUrl);
        let resourcesNextUrl = getResourceByUrl(nextUrl);

        // Diff resources
        ACCESS DATA FROM ABOVE VARIABLES HERE!

        // Return new resources            
    }


    function getResourceByUrl (url)
    {
        let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        let xmlResponse;

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                // when succesfull
                var resources = extractResourcesFromXMLResponse(this.response);
                return resources;                   
            }
        };


        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }


    function extractResourcesFromXMLResponse (xmlResponse)
    {
        let resources = [];

        // Add images
        imagePaths = extractImages(xmlResponse);
        resources.push(imagePaths);
        return resources;
    }

    function extractImages(xmlDoc) 
    {
        let match,
            extractedImages = [],
            newArr = [],
            rex = /<img.*?src="([^">]*\/([^">]*?))".*?>/g;

        while ( match = rex.exec( xmlDoc ) ) {
            extractedImages.push( match[1] );
        }

        return extractedImages;
    }
```

How do I acces the returned `resource` variable in the `getNewResource()` function

Comment: *how to differentiate the resources* ????

Comment: Before you attempt to fix `extractResourcesFromXMLResponse`, you should probably take a [read of this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Comment: @JamesThorpe better like this/